# Overlapping Issue on Ajax Call: Success

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am facing with overlapping problem after Ajax Call. I am using a plug-in called "[Nerve Slider](http://www.ryanbruzan.net/work/plugins/nerve-slider/)" for my grid layout(as you see in [here](http://www.ryanbruzan.net/work/plugins/puzzle-grid) (on the far right)).

After I did this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.kategori-link').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo base_url('tr/main/index'); ?>',
            data: {kategori:'ucak-bileti'},
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data){

              var result = $('<div />').append(data).find('.iAmTest').html();
              $('.iAmTest').html(result);
              //console.log(result);
            },

            error: function(){
                alert("Sorry! Something went wrong!");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

All grids (Each grid has Image, Header, Info as you see in the link above) which I got after database interaction are overlapped! What do you think causes this to happen?

Thank you!

**EDIT**
Plug-in Scripts:

```
$(function(){
    $(".slider-wrapper").nerveSlider({
        sliderWidth: "100%",
        slideTransitionSpeed: 700,
        slideTransitionEasing: "easeInOutExpo",
        slidesDraggable: true,
        sliderResizable: true,
        sliderFullscreen: false
        }); 
});

$(function(){
    $(".cnt-slider-wrapper").nerveSlider({
        sliderAutoPlay: false,
        slideTransitionSpeed: 700,
        slideTransitionEasing: "easeInOutExpo",
        slidesDraggable: true,
        sliderResizable: true,
        sliderFullscreen: false,
        showPause: false
        });
    $(".iAmTest").puzzleGrid({
    // options...
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may or may not work, I have not tested this.

While not a clean solution, you can call `$(window).trigger("resize");` after your `$('.iAmTest').html(result);` line. The plugin script has a function called `setuppanels();` that is attached to the window resize event. That re-initialises the content.

Comment: thanks for solution! This worked for overlapping problem. But slider functionality still does not work. It resized to normal size of slider wrapper but picture in slider looks smaller than its wrapper and it doesn't slide out. It does not initialize or can not find the script of plugin? No error catched by the way.

Comment: I solved by adding "plug-in scripts" into the ajax "complete" function.